# Matlab changing y-axis tick values

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab

I have a plot in which the y-axis ticks are like `2.400400e-01`. I do not like this, I need to make it shorter and understandable. How is it possible? I used :

```
set(gca, 'YTickLabel', num2str(get(gca,'YTick')','%d'))
```

Comment: Do you want to change what the increments actually are or just how they are displayed?

Comment: @Ian, thanks, Just how they are displayed  e.g `0.24004` instead of `2.400400e-01`

Comment: But do you actually want all those digits, or is the problem just with the scientific notation?

Comment: Actually the best presentation would be like `2.4*10^(-4), 2.3*10^(-4), 2.2*10^(-4) , ...` . Also I have to locate these axis ticks specifically.

Comment: Guys, now I use `set(gca, 'YTickLabel', num2str(get(gca,'YTick')','%.5f'))`          which is much more nice-looking. But I still insist using exponentials such as `10^(-4)...` with `sprintf` .. Do you know how to do?

Comment: I don't think you're going to find an easy standard utility that renders the scientific notation with "10^" instead of "e". You would probably need to homebrew that yourself (which is admittedly pretty straightforward string processing).

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer from MathWorks. I will share it for future reference. This gives what we are looking for.

```
`hAx = gca;                                                      % Get Axis Handle
% hAx.YScale = 'log';                                           % Set Y-Scale To Logarithmic
ytix = hAx.YTick;                                               % Get Y-Tick Values
ytix_exp = fix(log10(ytix));                                    % Y-Tick Label Exponents
ytix_exp(~isfinite(ytix_exp)) = 0;                              % Set ‘-Inf’ To ‘0’
ytix_mnt = 10.^rem(log10(ytix),1);                              % Y-Tick Label Mantissas
ytix_mnt(~isfinite(ytix_mnt)) = 0;                              % Set ‘NaN’ To ‘0’
% ytkstr = sprintf('%.6f 10^{%d}\n', [ytix_mnt; ytix_exp]);       % Create Strings For Y-Labels, Choose Mantissa Format As: '%.5f'
ytkstr = sprintf('%.6f 10^{%d}\n', [ytix_mnt; ytix_exp ]);
ytix_lbl = regexp(ytkstr, '\n', 'split');                       % Separate Strings To Create Y-Tick Labels
ytix_lbl{1} = '0';                                              % Set First Y-Yick Label To '0'
set(hAx, 'YTick',ytix', 'YTickLabel',ytix_lbl) `
```